# What are the 'structures' of structuralism?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Structuralism has for many become *the* buzzword in the philosophy of mathematics in the past 30 or so years. My question can be stated simply as:

> What are the structures of structuralism?

Mathematics tend to think of structures as consisting of domains equipped with some functions (consider the structures of abstract algebra for example: groups, rings etc.) Clearly these structures are not viable candidates, since groups etc. themselves must exist as 'points' in some other, more general structure when we define relationships between them. This leads me to think a category theoretic approach would be best, but I am interested to see if anyone can recommend any reading here.

Comment: Lots of interesting readings here. The leading man, on the category theory side, for me, is [Steve Awodey](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/awodey/). The Oxford Handbook of Philosophy of Math and Logic has two good survey articles (by Hellman and by MacBride). I'm sure SEP has relevant stuff too in philosophy of math topics.

Comment: N.b. that *Structuralism* in philosophy usually refers to something else. See http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/foucault/

Comment: In *SEP* see : [Philosophy of Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philosophy-mathematics) and at least S.Shapiro, *Philosophy of Mathematics: Structure and Ontology* (1997), Oxford: Oxford University Press and M.Resnik, *Mathematics as a Science of Patterns* (1997), Oxford: Clarendon Press.

Comment: @virmaior of course, de Saussure's idea in structuralist linguistics that the individual sign is arbitrary and that signs gain their meaning from their *relations* to other signs, and the sociological idea that culture might be modelled in terms of a language organised by signs so related, is very much in step with the Shapiro/Resnik idea of restricting our interest to mathematical *Theories* whose objects are conceived of as *Positions* in structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of Structuralism is made explicit by Jean Piaget in his "little" book, "Structuralism", 1970

*Wholeness*, where elements are governed by laws & not just an aggregate composite
*Transformation*, dynamicity and change again according to rules or laws
 (In this sub-section 3 of the Introduction, on transformation, Piaget, referencing Godel' methods, is adamant that the relation between structuralism and constructivism is no longer avoidable. (That intuition provides much of what we then proceed to axiomize.)
And thirdly, *Self-regulation* (& self-maintenance) which involves rhythm, regulation and operation as the mechanism

In "Structuralism", also, Piaget cites the French group know as the Bourbaki. Piaget, however also states on p.27 of a chapter called "Mathematical and Logical Structures" and two years before Mac Lane's "Categories for the Working Mathematician" the following.

What we have in mind are the "categories" of MacLane, Eilenburg, and others' The "categories" of of the new branch of the Bourbaki school are *classes which comprise "functions" and therefore "morphisms" among their elements* (a function, in the usual acceptance of the word, being the application of one set to another [or itself], obviously engenders isomorphisms, in fact every variety of "morphism".)

Then on P. 28 he cites S. Papert's observation that "MacLane's categories are a device for laying hold of mathematical operations rather than of "mathematics" itself: they constitute yet another example of that reflective abstraction which derives its substance, not from objects, but from operations performed upon objects even when the latter are themselves products of reflective abstraction"

In "Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists" Benjamin C. Pierce quotes in the preface
  What we are probably seeking is a "purer" view of functions: a theory of functions in themselves, not a theory of functions derived from sets. What, then, is a pure theory of functions? Answer: category theory --Scott [104,p.406]

What comes to mind when thinking about "pure" functions is the combinators invented by Moses Schönfinkel before Church's lambda-calculus.
Combinatory logic is a computation model equal to the lambda calculus, but without lambda-abstraction, that is, no substitutions
What combinatory logic does is the same as a basic term rewriting system. A reduction system.
See the article in the on-line "Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy" "Combinatory Logic"

But what also comes to mind  is constructive or Martin-Löf type theory that is yet another alternative to the foundations of mathematics.
Their *are* categorical models of type theory. One model is Local Cartesian Closed Categories or LCCC, Seely & refined by Hoffman & Cybjer.

Also universal algebra (A.N. Whitehead) is very similar to category theory by creating algebraic structure of closed sets of operations and data. (What object oriented programming aspires to but doesn't know it except for the writers of Smalltalk and Java)

If structuralism is to describe all such systems and mathematics itself, it needs formal definition.

Piaget may have been off to a good start in this respect as what he describes is either automata or a cybernetic system.
J. Richard Buchi says in "Finite Automata, Their Algebras and Grammars", Dirk Siefkes, ed that the theory of automata subsumes all algebraic systems including universal algebra so I assume category theory, too. That is we can write a categorical theoretic program in Haskell or SASL. (I've a book by M. Arbib "Arrows, Structures, and Functors: The Categorical Imperative" where, I think the subtitle is "Thinking in Arrows")

There's a number of books on category theory that do not require a PhD in mathematics

Here is another "Categories, Types and Structures: An Introduction to Category Theory for the Working Computer Scientist", Andrea Asperti and Giuseppe Longo, 1991

Comment: I haven't come across Piagets book on Structuralism before. It certainly sounds interesting on the possibility of admixture between Structuralism in Maths & the Humanities.

Comment: Piaget uses philosophy as background to structuralist ideas which he was pursuing for his own purpose of the science of cognitive development. The focus of his work and research is science only, not humanities. Science includes maths & logic. Pieget like most math & logic researchers are constructivists. The heuristic principles of constructivism, I believe are greater than that of structuralism. Constructive math & logic have produced more results. I also find it congruent to the ideas of Maturana in "The Tree of Knowledge: The Biological Root of Human Understanding". Science, also a tool.

Comment: @fpmora Many thanks for this response - I was unfamiliar with this work of Piagets, so I'm grateful for you pointing me in that direction. If you have any recommendations for more up-to-date reading on a category-theoretic interpretation of mathematical structuralism I'd be interested to learn of it. In the mean time, I have accepted your very useful answer.

Comment: Thank you for getting me to think about this fascinating subject about which I know very little.
Although, automata & cybernetics are manifestations of the "process" they are not necessarily the (abstract) process or structure preserving of category theory, that is of functors.
There is a remarkable little article on Wiki "Category Theory" that points to even more on-line resources. It also opened my eyes to better understand the work of Emmy Noether, who, I also didn't know was Saunder Mac Lane's teacher. Thank you, yet again!

Answer (score 2):

Structuralism in Mathematics goes back to Bourbaki when it was understood that the important thing about mathematical objects is not just its structure but also structure preserving maps.

Levi-Strauss who was the originator of structural anthropology which is essentially comparative anthropology remarked that Structuralism in his sense was taken from Saussure and not Bourbaki. The remark showed though he was aware of some similarity in the general tendency of the idea between these two fields - but of course it is in the specifics which brings out the richness of the idea, and in this, being two manifestly dfferent fields they differed widely.

Historically it was MaClane & Eilenberg who abstracted the notion of structure to create a new mathematical discipline called Category Theory. MaClane said that they purloined 'Category' from Kant. It was in fact the use of structure in Algebraic Topology that they were interested in formalising.

Since then, this 'abstract nonsense', has cast its net further and wider. It has been mooted as providing different foundations for mathematics particularly by Lawvere who called for a theory of sets without elements.

In traditional set theory, one can discren three elemental ideas:

1. the membership relation
2. the Subset relation
3. The idea of function

Its by formalising the idea of membership, and regarding that as the fundamental relationship that gives the idea of Sets

Mereology instead regards the subset relation as fundamental - the idea of part to whole.

Category theory instead takes the idea of function seriously. They are able to express the other ideas of set theory simply in terms of this. For example, the idea of a member of a set is thought of a function from any one-point set to the set and this picks out the elements.

A gentle introduction to these ideas is in Conceptual Mathematics by Schanuel, and to see how Structuralism is used in Set Theory - Sets for Mathematics by Lawvere is pitched at an introductary level but has all the essential ideas.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the help. This is a very valuable dialogue, clarifies much more for me on Category Theory.

Comment: Sure thing. Philosophers who are interested in CT if even tangentially are apparently few on the ground. So, onlyglad to help. If you have any other questions regarding CT just ask. I only found about mereology recently myself. One way of looking about it dispenses with the idea of a point which takes to the discussion back to Aristotle.

Comment: So true, indeed. That is one of the reasons why I appreciate Whitehead because he has much to contribute in this regard. And he definitely took many questions and issues back to Aristotle or Plato as many people will say based on the very little that they know about him.